# Shell script Copy file from one directory to another not working

Tags: linux, bash, android, shell-script, jenkins

Hi I am trying to automate the android build system through jenkins. Here I am trying to copy the image file from one directory to another directory but always getting " No such file or directory"

```
SRC=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android\ Gradle\ test\ build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/logo_splash.png
DEST=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android\ Gradle\ test\ build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable/logo_splash.png

cp -rf  $SRC $DEST
```

Error log:
cp: target `build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable/logo_splash.png' is not a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Word-Splitting

Protect your parameter strings and expansions from word-splitting by wrapping them in **"quotes"**. Notice how the following examples are colour-coded differently? It's revealing the differences between how the words are being grouped and separated.

You may or may not actually  even need to **\ escape\** the file path's **white-space** anymore, either.

---

### Quoted

```
src="/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android\ Gradle\ test\ build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/logo_splash.png"
dest="/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android\ Gradle\ test\ build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable/logo_splash.png"

cp -rf  "$src" "$dest"
```

### Un-Quoted

```
SRC=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android\ Gradle\ test\ build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/logo_splash.png
DEST=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android\ Gradle\ test\ build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable/logo_splash.png

cp -rf  $SRC $DEST
```

Comment: Yeah I missed the quotes, now I able to copy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what in particular you try to set for both variables but the result command will be expanded as:

```
cp -rf /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android Gradle test build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/logo_splash.png /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android Gradle test build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable/logo_splash.png
```

This means that you try to copy the first 7 arguments

```
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android
Gradle
test
build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/logo_splash.png 
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android
Gradle
test
```

to final destination:

```
build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable/logo_splash.png
```

which in fact should be a folder because of multiple source arguments.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cp -f  "$SRC" "$DEST"
```

- quote will cope for space in file name
- no need for `-r` (recursive)

Comment: Yeah I missed the quotes, now I able to copy. Thanks